# How to improve performance of relatively large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a relatively large table (currently 3 million records). Which has columns:

```
[id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[runId] INT NOT NULL,
[request] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[response] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
```

And an Index as : `CONSTRAINT [Id_Indexed] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

I have view on this table.

when I do query as:

```
Query 1 on table -- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM API (nolock) WHERE runId = 22

Query 2 on view  -- SELECT COUNT(*) FROM API_View WHERE runId = 22
```

Then I will get result around 1 million, but time taken by query 1 has taken 16 minutes while query 2 has taken 18 minutes.

Does it possible to improve this?

Comment: Add index on runId column and you will be happy

Comment: 3 million is SMALL, not large. Not relatively large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people already mentioned use add an index to the column run id.

Depending on how the table is used, you can think about using "with (nolock)"-hint. In some cases it can improve the performance a lot. Read here for further information:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/

Another advise (but not regarding your performance issue): Check whether you really need varchar(max), often varchar(255) would fit better. varchar(max) uses more space on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.API_View
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT runId, cnt = COUNT_BIG(*) 
    FROM dbo.API
    GROUP BY runId
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.API_View (runId)
GO

SELECT cnt
FROM dbo.API_View WITH(NOEXPAND)
WHERE runId = 22
```

or

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.API (runId)
GO

SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM API --WITH(INDEX(ix))
WHERE runId = 22
```

or

```
EXEC sp_tableoption 'dbo.API', 'large value types out of row', 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

ok,

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_RunId] ON [Table]([RunId]);
```

and run the queries again.